# Restore closed webpage at that time

Tags: browser, safari, browser-cache, webpage

I want to find an order number through the browser history. The browser history has the full link for the page when the order was finished, but it is no longer valid in the website. Is there any way to recover whatever was shown when I finished the purchase?

I used Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a dynamically-created page, then it's gone.

If you'd saved it at the time as a .webarchive, that would have preserved its state at that moment in time.

E.g. this, saved before I answered…
Even refreshing this after reopening doesn't add my answer to it. It's now static, no longer linked to the original page. The links in it, however, will still click through correctly [to the current dynamic version of each link].

[image]

Click for full size.

Comment: Thank you. The webarchive is not automatically saved by the browser I guess.

Comment: No, it's a manual save process.